# The resource cannot be find - .net web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've been trying for a while to make an rest api endpoint. However, when I test, it says that "The resource cannot be found." in the web browser.

This is my controller (part of it). The method isn't accessed.

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/ticket")]
public class TicketController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ITicketService _TicketService = new TicketService();

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("Prepare/{number:string}")]
    public TicketViewModel Prepare(string number)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

This is my registered route from RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default api with parameter",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{number}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Ticket",
        action = "Prepare",
        number = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You are mixing up MVC and Web API route attributes and route configurations. Look at the namespaces you are using for your attributes. The `RoutePrefix` uses the correct namespace while the others do not.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up MVC and Web API route attributes and route configurations. Look at the namespaces you are using for your attributes.

The `RoutePrefix` uses the correct namespace while the others do not.

Update the controller

```
using System.Web.Http;

[RoutePrefix("api/ticket")]
public class TicketController : ApiController {
    private readonly ITicketService _TicketService = new TicketService();

    //GET api/ticket/Prepare/123456789
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Prepare/{number}")]
    public TicketViewModel Prepare(string number) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

There is no `:string` route constraint as string is the default.

As for configuration, Web API configuration is usually found in the `WebApiConfig.Register` function where you would enable attribute routing and configure any convention-based routes.

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: WebApiConfig is not available in the project that I'm working on. Only RouteConfig is available. Should I create the first (where?) and delete the latter?

Comment: @AbcXyz Review the link provided in the answer and follow.

Comment: Could I as well change to mvc? Seems to be easier because RouteConfig is already written for mvc.